# Color of Krishna's Garud-dhwaj flag?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, vaishnavism, garuda

There are many accounts of Krishna using a flag with the Garuda Emblem on his chariot. I'd like to know if the color of the flag is mentioned anywhere?